# Created a fresh database, now running any artisan command throws an error about a missing table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I wanted a fresh development database so I could seed with new data, so I manually dropped and recreated my development database and now running any artisan commands throws an error. I continuously get an error saying that I'm missing a table.

```
In Connection.php line 647:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydatabase.stores'   
  doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `stores`)                                   


In PDOConnection.php line 63:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydatabase.stores'   
  doesn't exist                                                                


In PDOConnection.php line 61:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydatabase.stores'   
  doesn't exist
```

I haven't run `php artisan migrate:refresh` in a long time so I'm not sure where the table `stores` is being used that's causing this error. Adding a `-v` flag doesn't provide any additional output to further trace the stack.

I've tried manually dropping the database and recreating it via the mysql. I've tried `composer dump-autoload` but that doesn't help either. I can't run `php artisan migrate:install` because calling ANY artisan command will throw the same error. Even calling `php artisan` throws the error. I've tried looking at my service providers to see if the table is being referenced in any of the constructors but I don't see it being used.

Is there anywhere in the code I should be checking for the use of this table? I'm not sure what is instantiated when `php artisan` is called.

The `stores` table is actually my first migration, so it's supposed to be the first thing created, but for some reason it's being called as a part of the artisan process.

Comment: You can try `grep -R stores *` from the root of your directory, and `grep -R Store *`, or whatever the class name is. You'll probably want to check for anything in the __construct() method of any of your commands, as well, since it loads every single artisan command class whenever artisan is run

Comment: @aynber That was the solution, check my answer. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Welcome! I learned it the hard way a few years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @aynber in the comment to my question, the problem was several of my commands in the app/Console/Commands/* directory were instantiating an object in its constructor that referenced the Store model in its parent constructor. Specifically, it was running the line

```
$this->storeId = Store::get()->last()->id;
```

Commenting out this line allowed me to run my artisan commands.